# Using JS Methods in jQuery

Tags: jquery

In the following code snippet, the String.fromCharCode is used, can all JS methods be used within jQuery?

Perhaps a noob question, but better to ask and prove a noob, then assume and be a fool.

```
 // Invoke setBodyClass when a key is pressed
$(document).keyup(function(){
    switch (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)){
      case 'D':
        setBodyClass('default');
        break;
      case 'N':
        setBodyClass('narrow');
        break;
      case 'L':
        setBodyClass('large');  
        break;
    }

});//end keyup
```

Answer (score 3):

in one word -- absolutely.  And I think the only stupid question is the one not asked.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery *is* Javascript, so you may use any type of Javascript logic with jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

> can all JS methods be used within jQuery

Yes. jQuery is just a library of JavaScript functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all javascript functions can be used with jQuery. jQuery is just a plug-in that adds to javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Yes since jQuery ***IS*** JavaScript any and all JavaScript can be used in conjunction with it.

Comment: Many Thanks for all the encouraging replies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. jQuery is a javascript library

Answer (score 1):

> can all JS methods be used within jQuery?

Yes.  jQuery is a library, not a replacement language.